# can i use CSSTranforming with GWT?

Tags: gwt, css

Is there a option to use CSSTransforming with GWT?

I want to scale an image. So I have set a stylename to the the image and define it in my css-rules:

```css
.zoomedCard{
   -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
   border-color:red;
   -webkit-border-radius:1em;
   -moz-border-radius:1em;
   border-radius:1em;
}
.zoom:hover{
   -webkit-transform:scale(2);
   -moz-transform:scale(2);
   -o-transform:scale(2);
   -ms-transform:scale(2);
}
```

When I test it in normal html document it works great but with gwt, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The current rev of GWT (2.4) does not support CSS3 in the CSSResource parser. You can:

- Use a 3rd party library to enable CSS3 transitions with GWT
- Insert these programmatically at runtime
- Wait until these are enabled in GWT 2.5 this summer.

Not a great help, I know :( but it should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve been trying to use CSS3 transition in GWT. It flickers all the way. Need to wait till v2.5